# Setting Axios Header to Java Backend based on value stored in express session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, axios

I have a node.js express (server-side rendering) frontend app that calls java backend endpoints. I use Axios to call the java endpoints. I need to set a header named "agent-id" into every request express makes to java, the value of that header comes from the express session (`req.session`).

My Axios code is on another module. I'm importing that module and calling my APIs.

Currently my Axios module code is setup like so:

```js
const axiosClient = axios.create({
 baseURL: '...',
 httpsAgent: null,
 proxy: false,
 timeout: 60000,
});

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(request => {
 console.log(`Starting:${request.baseURL}${request.url}`);

 // HOW DO I SET HEADER FROM EXPRESS SESSION HERE //

 return request;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(response => {
 console.log(`Received from:${response.config.baseURL}${response.config.url}`);
 return response;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));

module.exports = axiosClient;
```

and I call my APIs from frontend express app like so:

```js
import api from 'my-api-module';

const { data = {} } = await api.someName();
```

**What I've tried**

I tried updating `req.headers` using a `app.use` middleware but I could not find that header within  the axios interceptor.

Ideally I dont want to change my entire API calling structure by passing `req` obj on every existing API calls, so is there anyway I can globally set the header using express session value for every Java request ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I figured there is no easy way to do a global change so I had to send the headers manually on each API calls.

```js
import api from 'my-api-module';

const { data = {} } = await api.someName({
  headers: {
    'custom-header': 'value'
  }
});
```

and on the interceptor, I did:

```js
axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(request => {
 console.log(`Starting:${request.baseURL}${request.url}`);

  if (request?.data?.headers) {
    request.headers = { ...request.headers, ...request.data.headers }
    delete request.data.headers;
  }

 return request;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));
```

PS: Not the best solution but I'm planning to completely re-write the Axios module to make it more modular